# Local Server Website Doesn't respond as soon as lose Internet Connectivity

Tags: proxy, windows-server-2012-r2, local-area-network, iis-8

I have hosted a local website in my organisation where student are accessing the local website locally from IIS server windows 2012 r2 Server,and we have 24 x 7 internet connectivity where the same server work out as proxy server for all other system.

Now problem is that when i loose internet connectivity i am not able to access the local website i have hosted in that server or it respond very slowly.Why?

I am not able to find out any solution for this please want suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, how many network interfaces are on this server?

On servers that have DHCP assigned IP (that is on the internet facing interface): localhost (127.0.0.1) may be bound to the interface assigned by the DHCP server, when this assignment is off / changes (i.e. DHCP that gives you internet connectivity), you have a different IP, and thus DNS for:

1. localhost mapping to IP assigned when internet is on, will not work when it is off
2. localserver.organisation.com -> IP also assigned when internet is on, will not work when it is off

What needs to be done is that:

Since this is a "local website locally from IIS server windows 2012 r2 Server", bind the domain to the IP (interface) that is on the LAN side, not the one on the internet side.

Steps:

1. Open IIS
2. Browse to the website on the left panel of IIS, and select the WEBSITE (if you host the site inside a website, CHOOSE THE WEBSITE, not the sub folder: e.g. Default Website on most IIS implementations, or if you created a new one)
3. Right click the website, and click Manage // Advanced Settings, whatever the option is there that displays where you can view the site settings

   4. If the website is bound to 127.0.0.1, or localhost, CHANGE THIS, specify it to be that IP that is facing your LAN (preferably a static one I suppose)

I think that should work, otherwise you may provide info on your interfaces by typing `ipconfig` in command prompt, we can find other ways to assist you.

The essense of the matter is, 127.0.0.1 / localhost may bind to the interface that falls when internet connection goes down, so the IP may down to the default 169.x.x.x assigned by MS servers: this won't be accessible from your LAN. (Not so sure about being slow, my solution is for CAN'T access)